# TypeScript doesn't throw an error when expected number of returned values is wrong

Tags: typescript

*For the sake of time and simplicity, the code examples in this question are simplified.*

I have a function that takes in an array of objects and for each object in that array it creates a variation of a product. Then, it returns all of the variations as an array of those variation objects.

```
const generateProducts = (productMockData: object[]) => {
    const products = productMockData.map((mockData) => {
         // create a variation of the product based on mock data
         const productVariation = ...
         
         return productVariation;
    })

    return [...products]
}
```

Here's an example of how this function is used:

```
const [productVariation1, productVariation2] = generateProducts([{color: 'red', price: 20}, {color: 'green', price: 100}])
```

In the example above, we passed in an array of two objects to the **generateProducts** function, so the function returns an array of exactly two variation objects.

**The issue is that if you accidentally expect an array of three objects to be returned from the function, instead of two, TypeScript doesn't throw an error.**

```
const [productVariation1, productVariation2, productVariation3] = generateProducts([{color: 'red', price: 20}, {color: 'green', price: 100}])
```

**In this case, we expect to have three variations of a product, but there are only two, since we only passed two to the generateProducts function. Still, TypeScript doesn't throw an error.**

Is there a way to get better TypeScript support for this use case?

Comment: TypeScript does not do run-time checking, if you want a run-time type guard you'll need to implement it yourself. This said, none of your code has an implied length, so you should assume even `result[0]` could be _undefined_

Comment: If you can pass input as rest parameter https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AFQK5gDYQDxoB8UAvFAN5QDaA0lAJYB2UA1hCAPYBmUaAugC4oHRCmBQAvgFgAULOQdGAZ3EBzCIwgAnAIbAIABS0cAJhlRLSUPAagQAHvsYnLIpKip9CACgB0-sGMzVABZDmQWABE9HSEDAEoheHd0LFwbYhJiclkoPKgtCGAMLWZA03NgMIjo4B1fAFsdMG9vBvComPjSbNz8-oB6AahkQr1oHSgANx0tej16RWEeYAALaHLg8TgdJQgTYWZ2iKgTGL7+vIVlcU3KgDVZ+eBF5jJKf0aO2snpORlLvlCsVSlA7qhHnMFooANwXSTdXawUSoTA4fAGQiyP7yRQqajg4CQ56vACMABowUEHk9oYwAEyUwnEukAZj4pHh6k0un0RgqFm8lAU2A4WiEAHJCiYJUy5sgIEJ6QAGSSU4UcUXiqAS1SFDSyqn0BVCUnK1USeJAA

Comment: @AlekseyL. this only works because the data is hardcoded, as soon as you switch to a type of `object[]` (length any number) the tuple checking will go back to not complaining, e.g. https://cutt.ly/xUS3VwO

Comment: Yes, in my case, the data is dynamic, as it comes from a CMS...

Comment: @PaulS. yeah, of course, only static analysis

Comment: For unknown number of elements destrcutring like `const [productVariation1, productVariation2, productVariation3]` doesn't make a lot of sense..

Answer (score 2):

In what follows I will ignore the implementation of `generateProducts()` and assume it has the following call signature:

```
declare const generateProducts: (productMockData: object[]) => object[];
```

---

Unless you enable [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess), the compiler will assume that you will always get a defined element if you read from  an [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) via a numeric index.  It ignores the possibility that there is no element at the index (e.g., the index is negative, or not an integer, or past the end of the array, etc.)  If you read the third element of an array that happens to have only two elements, you will get `undefined` at runtime but the compiler will completely miss this.

One thing you *could* do here is enable `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`, which would address the situation by forcing you to deal with possible `undefined` values:

```
const [productVariation1, productVariation2, productVariation3] =
  generateProducts([{ color: 'red', price: 20 }, { color: 'green', price: 100 }])

if ("color" in productVariation3) { } // <-- error, Object is possibly 'undefined'
if (productVariation3 && "color" in productVariation3) { } // <-- okay
```

but this is often more trouble than it's worth; the same check will have to happen for `productVariation1`, which you know exists:

```
if ("color" in productVariation1) { } // error, grr
if (productVariation1 && "color" in productVariation1) { } // forcing me to check
```

which will tempt you to skip the check by using a [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
if ("color" in productVariation1!) { } // <-- I assert this is fine
```

and if you get used to using such assertions, then you might *overuse* them, which  leads you back to the same problem as before with `productVariation3`, with some extra steps:

```
if ("color" in productVariation3!) { } // <-- I assert this is fine, wait oops
```

And as such, the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option is not included in [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).  If you want to use it and it helps you, great.  But otherwise, you might want to take a different approach.

---

A different way of looking at things is that your `generateProducts()` call signature currently returns an array of unknown length.  But if you know that the returned array will always have the same length as the input array, then you can try to take advantage of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types); make `generateProducts()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function which tries to figure out the exact `length` of its input (via [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) notation), and then have it return a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) which of the same length (but possibly a different element type).  For example:

```
declare const generateProducts: <T extends object[]>(
  productMockData: [...T]) => { [I in keyof T]: object };
```

And now when we call it with an array of known length, you can see that the compiler keeps that length in the output type:

```
const ret =
  generateProducts([{ color: 'red', price: 20 }, { color: 'green', price: 100 }]);
// const ret: [object, object]
```

And this immediately gives you the error you want and only where you want it:

```
const [productVariation1, productVariation2, productVariation3] = // error!
  // --------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Tuple type '[object, object]' of length '2' has no element at index '2'
  generateProducts([{ color: 'red', price: 20 }, { color: 'green', price: 100 }])
```

The compiler knows that `productVariation1` and `productVariation2` are defined, while `productVariation3` is not:

```
// const productVariation1: object
// const productVariation2: object
// const productVariation3: undefined
```

This is pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

The big caveat here is that the compiler does not track the exact length of all arrays.  If you pass an array literal directly into `generateProducts()`, the compiler will pay attention to the length, but in most cases an array literal will be widened to an array and not have its "tuple-ness" maintained:

```
const objects = [{ color: "red" }, { color: "green" }];
// const objects: { color: string; }[]
```

The above `objects` is an arbitrary array of `{color: string}` elements, and the compiler does not know how many such elements there are.  If you pass *that* to `generateProducts()`, then you get the old behavior again:

```
const oops = generateProducts(objects);
// const oops: object[]
```

The compiler has no idea how many elements are in `oops`, and so if you destructure that into a bunch of variables, each one will either be of type `object` or of type `object | undefined` depending on the status of the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option.

This caveat probably shouldn't come as much of surprise; the situations in which a compiler can keep track of the exact number of elements in an array are pretty limited by necessity.  Arrays are quite often used to hold an arbitrary and variable amount of data, and quite often are supplied by or modified by code that the compiler cannot access or fully analyze.  So for the general case you're probably stuck with having the compiler be lax and let you read elements off the end of the array or strict and scold you into null-checking elements you know to be defined.  But in the specific scenario like your example, where you write TypeScript code by calling a function and directly pass it an array literal of a known number of elements, you can get some stronger typing and nicer behavior.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJJAelKQEkByAN2QBcBXNYCAEyQHtgkBaPsC4BVYPAAWEeAGsOlYOwgAPDgEF4iKFCIlF8ADYg0yeDygMkWCGzQgGEAApou7JvAZQAXEgAUMZ67uALJcMgAidiDeXABGAFZSDADaALoAlEgAvAB83PGJqQDcRDpIpsDmSEn+Lm4MAGpGGHYYPACMADRINYENTS08AExdPXWNmAPAAMwpWaUkVjZ2jgF1UD5JuGVc+lxo3tTG7NQjmIjegwAMSAC+XVumu-tI1FjG1ifdZxDebZfXN3SJWIX1q7nGzQYrWAbTIFHKlVG4P6UPa0Xy7iQAB8kEwFBAAGYYNjsUpIvoTVHAQZw7YVCzkiGTQbohKYnF4xREklk1bIynQqa0hEMvkUyGC1mJbG4-HcjjAkgYAm+ABEjz2qqQxNBvSZVKmGS2N1pAB4BEgIGhnGguigMRYMFBulwtBgYvoAJ4vTmE4kcailZW+RkowVIABkEaQ6p2mu1vFDAp4hrwtzNFq40hAnsV2pVPljTy1OqTEvaRvT5Et1r2XTeaCDBbLk1hUZjGrQJcTYv10LalZN1YJe3gxJwkCQDC4ZUkMjzwcLne7urGYfaAEJBxm+FQkCAtFaLAxxE7tc75U21cuE6v+eXplu00OKObd5R94e0MfT86z-KugAdxADALC4LgYG0QgiBuYFQEgWAEGQAAVJgYH0aA8FKPRDGMOlKkWK1licMEPG8U1kMtJR7AUZ1YjZZIUmyHx5jvBgQnCSJvCSAA6PjkPSLJci2JIPx1WRPS4FUBKlTEbmKaCQRFJBjAsTJWMI2x7BI3p1k2bYngOI5Pn8DBziQK5bnuAy9gON4IA+U4zJ+JA-gBdIFNKatlNU7j6MSLp-PcFI82U6pe3XGFTlIvshmivVIpmLJaStG0N1Y6sBCy7KctyvL8qy3IAD8StKsrypKjKKFQ9DGE9GBkGoJIgoYQKHRSahuBVDDgCwE8XkGTrxAPJAhEtDDIGACw7ATRQlAGwMQQWawiO0sU9IeONnkOAMnPMyy7jTTs7PeYATO+X5-luIEQW8sxRRiyK2lkhgvPhe62Ni6kXre-CHoS5Npm8X15VJRSSGUlrnUyKpNsMmMji1Q64dsmN7OsJGUgUkg7vpPIGK8I6tu8cxMF6wpblSUKPvAyDks04j1p8KG0mx4UaYgwmWqpxTYMUoA)

Comment: By the way, you don't need to opt into `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` if you use [`Array.prototype.at(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) instead of `Array.prototype[n]` or `[item] = Array.prototype` when accessing elements.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your debuger is not trowing an error is that ists not an error...
Yourself have to decide if this "interaction" is valid or not.

Your generateProducts function looks great but if you want to validate if the program is trying to have 3 variation based on 2 model object (the parameters given to the function) I think you have to fundmental choices:

1- Create a class that implements you generateProducts function and a property that will hold your array with null variables => [null,null,null]
and then.

```js
export new ProductionHelper {

  public array: Array < object | ProductsVariation | null > = [];

  public generateProducts(productMockData: Array < ProductsVariation > ) {

    if (this.array.lentgth === productMockData.length) {
      let i = 0;
      productMockData.map((mockData) => {
        // create a variation of the product based on mock data
        **
        createdObj **

          this.array[i] = createdObj;
      });
      return this.array;
    } else {
      throw [
        return
      ] new Error("Number of variation is not equal to length of array");
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

Second solution is to had your returned array has second parameter for your function =>

```js
function generateProducts(productMockData: object[], productVar: object[])...
```